# determining how "important" a feature is in predicting a target in decision trees

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, random-forest, importance

> Random forests allow us to compute a heuristic for determining how
>   "important" a feature is in predicting a target. This heuristic
>   measures the change in prediction accuracy if we take a given feature
>   and permute (scramble) it across the datapoints in the training set.
>   The more the accuracy drops when the feature is permuted, the more
>   "important" we can conclude the feature is. Importance can be a useful
>   way to select a small number of features for visualization.

I have read about this method to select the important features in random forest. Can some one explain me what does scrambling a feature means in random forest??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have 1000 men and 1000 women, measure everyone's height and model height as predicted by sex. In your random forest context, you can assess predictive accuracy out-of-bag.

Now, if sex were irrelevant to height, then you should get (roughly) the same predictive accuracy if you randomly shuffled everyone's M/F identification.

That is exactly what RF variable importance does: shuffle each observation's value on one variable, reassess predictive accuracy and compare to accuracy on the unshuffled data. If the shuffled data predict as well as unshuffled data, the variable is obviously not very important for prediction. If the shuffled data predict worse, then the variable is important.

In this toy example, we only have one predictor. In a more general setting, you would do this on every predictor separately, that is, you'd shuffle one variable, leaving the others unchanged.

Comment: Now I got it!! so you used the term 'predictive accuracy out-of-bag' is this same as accuracy of the classifier??

Comment: Yes, but not assessed in-sample - in-sample fit will *always* over-estimate predictive accuracy. Instead, when the RF does its [bagging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating), some data points are left out of each bag sample - and we assess accuracy by predicting those, using the model fitted to the in-bag data. [Read this.](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/OOBestimation.pdf)

Comment: Sure I will read it. so out of bag error is used to find the optimum number of trees right??

Comment: That one too, if I remember random forests right. Breiman used out-of-bag in multiple places. Best to look up [his original paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1010933404324).